# Dropdown on change open a modal with data

Tags: coffeescript, modal-dialog, materialize, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Vendor dropdown in my rails app. I am trying to fetch some data using ajax and currently the returned data is simply displayed in a div on the same page.

I am wondering if it is possible to pass the vendor id to the modal and it then display add the records associated with the vendor after making the ajax call?

here is my current coffeescript code to retrieve the data and display in the div.

```
$ ->
if $('body.bills.new').length > 0
    $('body.bills.new #bill_vendor_id').change ->
        $.ajax
            url: '/purchase_orders/?vendor_id='+ $('body.bills.new #bill_vendor_id option:selected').val()
            success: (data) ->
                alert data
                $('#data').html data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is!

You can for example add the class of the dropdown you want to show in the #bill_vendor_id data.

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="bill_vendor_id" data-dropdown-class="something" ... />
```

And in the js you find the class and use it to hit the dropdown:

```
...
 $.ajax
    url: '/purchase_orders/?vendor_id='+ $('body.bills.new #bill_vendor_id option:selected').val()
      success: (data) ->
        div_class = $(this).data('dropdown-class')
        $('.' + div_class).html data
```

#### EDIT

Okay. Yes, it depends. Do you want to change all the html or append some html? 
You can either use `.html data` or `.append data`

And *remember* to show the modal, if you're not already doing this.

Comment: I am already doing the replacement of html in div. What I am looking for is to show a modal and in that modal show this data. Should I just find the div of the modal and replace its html?

Comment: I was looking for something like <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a> . but if something like that is not available then i guess will have to use what you suggested.